# Sleeping a boost thread for some nanoseconds

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, sleep

I want a boost thread to sleep for some nanoseconds. The following code is a sample that compiles without errors. However, it does not work as expected and I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
//Building options:
//-DBOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_thread-mt 
void replay()  
{
    boost::posix_time::time_duration time1, time2; 

    time1=boost::posix_time::seconds(3);
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(time1) << std::endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(time1);

    time2=boost::posix_time::nanoseconds(987654321);
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(time2) << std::endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(time2); 
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{  
    boost::thread replaythread(replay);  
    replaythread.join();
    return 0;  
}
```

The BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG is a preprocessor definition required in order to work with nanoseconds ([more info](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/details.html#date_time.buildinfo)). The problems occurs when I set the -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG building option, then the boost::this_thread::sleep does not work for any posix::time_duration. The created thread uses all the CPU and it does not sleep nor process the remaining instructions. If the preprocessor definition is removed, the thread can sleep for any time period unless boost::posix_time::nanoseconds. 
The program uses some time_duration variables to store nanoseconds and that makes the boost::this_thread::sleep not work.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: What do you mean with it does not work? Does it sleep to short or to long or not at all? What is the output of the std::cout line with the nanosecs?

Comment: You are right. I edited the post with a better description. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to link the program with debuginformation for boost and look what is happening while sleeping? For me it sounds like a busy waiting, which is clear as there is no other possibility to sleep for nanoseconds because thats far below the schedulers limits. Maybe the loop that is waiting never returns for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG` changes the size of `ptime`.

`boost::this_thread::sleep` is a compiled function, which was compiled (on your distro) without that define, so it expects microsecond-precision ptime arguments. You're passing nanosecond-precision ptime arguments, and the function fails.

If you extract the code from the boost library and compile it with this define enabled, the program works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

// the guts of boost_1_46_1/libs/pthread/thread.cpp's version of sleep()
boost::mutex sleep_mutex;
boost::condition_variable sleep_condition;
void mysleep(const boost::posix_time::time_duration& dur)
{
    boost::system_time st = boost::get_system_time() + dur;
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(sleep_mutex);
    while(sleep_condition.timed_wait(lk, st));
}

void replay()
{
    boost::posix_time::time_duration time1, time2;

    time1=boost::posix_time::seconds(3);
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(time1) << std::endl;
    mysleep(time1);
    //boost::this_thread::sleep(time1);

    time2=boost::posix_time::nanoseconds(987654321);
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(time2) << std::endl;
    mysleep(time2);
    //boost::this_thread::sleep(time2);
}
int main()
{
    boost::thread replaythread(replay);
    replaythread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (note that this code is demo-only, since my mutex and condvar are global, while in the real library they are nonstatic members of the boost::thread class)

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I am trying to build the thread library with that define using `b2`. I added the line  `variant new_release : release : <define>BOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG;` to the `user-config.jam` without success. Do you know where to include the define option?

Answer (score 2):

Some sleep functions return early when interupted so you have to check the return value of the function and call it again until they return zero.